# Как узнать координаты пользователя?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как можно узнать координаты пользователя (в градусах) или расскажите структуру? Есть ли какой нибудь плагин jQuery? (в дальнейшем эти пользователи буду отмечаться по своим координатам на карте google). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем проблема? :) [Google maps v3 plugin for jQuery and jQuery Mobile](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/).
P.S. глянь [`GeoLocation example`](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geolocation.html) для определения координат.